# Google maps is creating multiple rectangles instead of just one

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using draggable & editable rectangles to allow the user to select a specific area range, with the following code:

```
function init(lat, lng, northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng)
{
    var mapOptions =
    {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds
    (
        new google.maps.LatLng(northEastLat, northEastLng),
        new google.maps.LatLng(southWestLat, southWestLng),
    );

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(
    {
        bounds: bounds,
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    });

    rectangle.setMap(map);
}
```

**My objective**:

1. Only have one rectangle that the user can drag and expand as he wants
2. Save the coordinates of both Map & Rectangle as the next time he views the map its already in the correct coordinates

**My problems**:

1. It's showing 3 rectangles (?)
2. After saving in the database all the coordinates and refreshing the page, the rectangle is not in the right place (probably because its showing 3 rectangles..)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdex5b8v/)** illustrating the problem

**Image** illustrating the problem

[image]

**code snippet illustrating the problem:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latitude = $('#latitude').val();
  var longitude = $('#longitude').val();
  var northEastLat = $('#northeast_latitude').val();
  var northEastLng = $('#northeast_longitude').val();
  var southWestLat = $('#southwest_latitude').val();
  var southWestLng = $('#southwest_longitude').val();

  init(latitude, longitude, northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng);
});

function init(lat, lng, northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng) {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(northEastLat, northEastLng),
    new google.maps.LatLng(southWestLat, southWestLng),
  );

  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });

  rectangle.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', function(e) {
    var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
    var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

    $('#northeast_latitude').val(ne.lat());
    $('#northeast_longitude').val(ne.lng());
    $('#southwest_latitude').val(sw.lat());
    $('#southwest_longitude').val(sw.lng());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'dragend', function(e) {
    $('#latitude').val(e.latLng.lat());
    $('#longitude').val(e.latLng.lng());
  });
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 400px"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" value="41.17575333" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" value="-8.35380113" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  North East latitude: <input type="text" id="northeast_latitude" value="41.442726314556566" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  North East longitude: <input type="text" id="northeast_longitude" value="-8.04068304687496" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  South West latitude <input type="text" id="southwest_latitude" value="40.9306615083795" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  South West longitude <input type="text" id="southwest_longitude" value="-8.889999453125029" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the [`google.maps.LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.constructor) constructor takes the arguments (southWest, northEast), you are providing them in the other order (northEast, southWest), which gives you the inverse rectangle (wrapped around the word the other way).

> **LatLngBounds**
>   LatLngBounds([sw, ne])
>   Parameters: 
>   sw:  LatLng|LatLngLiteral optional
>   ne:  LatLng|LatLngLiteral optional

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qx71ut0n/1//)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latitude = $('#latitude').val();
  var longitude = $('#longitude').val();
  var northEastLat = $('#northeast_latitude').val();
  var northEastLng = $('#northeast_longitude').val();
  var southWestLat = $('#southwest_latitude').val();
  var southWestLng = $('#southwest_longitude').val();

  init(latitude, longitude, northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng);
});

function init(lat, lng, northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng) {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(southWestLat, southWestLng),
    new google.maps.LatLng(northEastLat, northEastLng),
  );

  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });

  rectangle.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', function(e) {
    var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
    var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

    $('#northeast_latitude').val(ne.lat());
    $('#northeast_longitude').val(ne.lng());
    $('#southwest_latitude').val(sw.lat());
    $('#southwest_longitude').val(sw.lng());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'dragend', function(e) {
    $('#latitude').val(e.latLng.lat());
    $('#longitude').val(e.latLng.lng());
  });
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 400px"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" value="41.17575333" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" value="-8.35380113" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  North East latitude: <input type="text" id="northeast_latitude" value="41.442726314556566" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  North East longitude: <input type="text" id="northeast_longitude" value="-8.04068304687496" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  South West latitude <input type="text" id="southwest_latitude" value="40.9306615083795" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  South West longitude <input type="text" id="southwest_longitude" value="-8.889999453125029" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you've created only one rectangle and not multiples, but what you are seeing is the opposite rectangle.

Based on your fiddle I only changed the bounds:

```
...
    bounds: {
          north: 41.442726314556566,
          south: 40.9306615083795,
          east: -8.04068304687496,
          west: -8.889999453125029,
        },
...
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps!